# How to get the number of words in a string

Tags: c++, string, set

I have an assignment due for my intro c++ class next week and I need some advice for how to go about doing it. I have to make a word count program that gives out the number of lines, words, characters, unique lines, and unique words in a users list input. So far, this is what I have:

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would put a line into a `std::istringstream`, and read words from there to count them. To count unique words/lines, it's almost certainly easiest to insert them into a `std::set`, then count the number of items in the set when you're done (which looks like pretty much what you're already attempting, so this is pretty much just a confirmation that this approach is entirely viable).

If you need to separate words without a stringstream, it's (generally) easiest to find a non-space character, then copy characters to a string until you encounter a space character again. Repeat until you reach the end of the input.

Comment: Is there another way of finding the words without using stringstream? My professor said we couldn't use that function since we haven't learned it yet. And also, let's say I store the lines into the set. I know that if I use the size() function I could get the number of unique lines. But, how could I get the number of unique words?

Comment: Once you separate out the words, storing them in a set, then counting the size will give the number of unique words.

Comment: could you show an example of how I could use springstream?

Comment: @user3403337: Using stringstream, you'd do something like: `std::set<std::string> unique_words; std::istringstream in(input); while (in >> word) ++word_count; unique_words.insert(word);`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably set up a counter (`words`) and a flag(`in_word`), starting at 0 and `false`. Read a character at a time. Depending of `in_word` and if the current character is a word-character or not, change state and possibly increment the number of words (essentially count word starts).

This sounds messy, but take a line (this one will do ;-) and see how it should go.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to write all the code for you, but here are the algorithms:

## Lines

Loop through the lines of the string using `getline` with newline as a delimiter.  For each line (if it's not empty?), increment the number of lines.

## Words

For each line, loop through the words using `getline` with a delimiter of space.  For each line, if it's not empty, increment the number of words.

## Characters

#### Counting spaces

`std::string.size()`

#### Not counting spaces

```
unsigned int numCharacters;
for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    if (str[i] != ' ') numCharacters++;
```

## Unique Lines/Words

Loop through the same way as counting the lines/words, but add each line to an `std::vector` -- `std::vector.push_back()` -- if it doesn't already contain the line.

Comment: So far, I have the words, characters, unique lines, and total lines. All I need to do is figure out how to place my words in a vector or set in such a way that will give me how many unique words I have.

Comment: @user3403337 If you have unique lines, then ignore my technique and apply the same algorithm to unique words.

Comment: So,what you're basically saying is, I need to apply the same algorithm I used for getting the unique lines to get the unique words?

Comment: @user3403337 Yep.  My approach again: keep a list of all the words you've encountered, and if you run into a word not on that list, add it.  If it's already on the list, don't add it.